# problems with alignment css / fcc project

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to build a product landing page as a certificate project for freeCodeCamp.

I can't understand how to fix the icons to the left, while fixing the feature and price to the center. And I can't understand why my `li` items are overflowing over their container.

I tried all the overflow and wrap tags I know but I can't work it out.

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

html {
  font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;
}

#logo {
  position: absolute;
  width: 25%;
  left: 0;
  height: auto;
  image-resolution: 100%;
}

header {
  width: 100%;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-evenly;
}

.navspace {
  justify-content: end;
  position: relative;
  right: -15%;
}

nav {
  positio: relative;
}

ul {
  display: flex;
  list-style: none;
}

li {
  margin: 40px;
}

.product {
  position: absolute;
  top: 15%;
}

#leads {
  width: 100vw;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  text-align: center;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

.title {
  padding: 2%;
}

#logo-green {
  width: 5vw;
  height: auto;
  margin-right: 5vw;
}

#Features {
  margin-left: 27%;
  display: flex;
  align-items: left;
  justify-content: left;
  text-align: left;
  padding: 5%;
}

#Price {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: left;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 3%;
  margin-left: 27%;
}

.price {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  text-align: left;
}

.pricelist {
  width: 100%;
  max-height: 400px;
  text-align: center;
  position: absolute;
  display: inline-flex;
  justify-content: center;
}

.class {
  width: 300px;
  height: 300px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  margin: 20px;
}

.class>h1 {
  width: 100%;
  height: 10%;
  background-color: blanchedalmond;
  padding: 2%;
  font-size: large;
}

#medium,
#pika,
#base {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.class>h2 {
  margin: 5% 0 5% 0;
}

.class>ul {
  display: grid;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  flex-direction: column;
  gap: 2px;
}

.class>li {
  position: relative;
}
```

```html
<link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Montserrat' rel='stylesheet'>

<!-- tabella nav -->
<header>
  <div>
    <img id="logo" src="img/LIGHTSPEED.png" alt="" />
  </div>
  <!-- bhr -->
  <div class="navspace">
    <nav id="nav-link">
      <ul>
        <li>Features</li>
        <li>Price</li>
        <li>Contacts</li>
      </ul>
    </nav>
  </div>
</header>
<main class="product">
  <!-- form -->
  <section id="leads">
    <h2 class="title">Most efficient way to light your life</h2>
    <form action="">
      <input class="email" type="email" required placeholder="Enter your email" columns="10">
      <input class="submit" type="submit" value="Get Shocked">
    </form>
  </section>
  <!-- features -->
  <section>
    <div id="Features">
      <div id="green">
        <img id="logo-green" src="img/294432.png" alt="">
      </div>
      <div class="feature">
        <h2>Only from renovable energy</h2>
        <p>Coming from water and earth termal energy</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </section>
  <!-- price -->
  <section>
    <div id="Price">
      <div id="cheap">
        <img id="logo-green" src="img/low-price.png" alt="">
      </div>
      <div class="price">
        <h2>Prices you have never seen</h2>
        <p>With our funding system you might get some solar panels</p>
        <p>and who knows... we might pay you your energy.</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </section>
  <div class="pricelist">
    <div class="class" id="base">
      <h1>BASE LEVEL</h1>
      <h2>49€</h2>
      <ul>
        <li>Standart power transmission</li>
        <li>Change power output by your personal profile</li>
        <li>Client Support 10am-20am</li>
      </ul>
    </div>
    <div class="class" id="medium">
      <h1>MEDIUM LEVEL</h1>
      <h2>59€</h2>
    </div>
    <div class="class" id="pika">
      <h1>PIKACHU LEVEL</h1>
      <h2>149€</h2>
    </div>
  </div>
</main>
```

Comment: Please read [ask]. Focus on **one** problem at a time. Provide a [mcve] (not *all* your code). Don't use image URLs that we can't resolve (services like https://placekitten.com/ exist). Use the stack snippets feature of the question editor to provide a live demo.

Comment: Hi and Welcome to SO. Please take the [tour] first and then read [ask]. After that edit your question and include a [repro] for debugging details (pay extra attention to the word **minimal**). Last but not least, read the description of the tags. `web` specifically states: `do not use this tag!`

Comment: In addition to the other comments above, a more specific title will help the right people find your question and help you out! (And will help people in the future looking to solve a similar issue.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A few things right off the bat, i've added some comments to your CSS. There's a lot going on here, and I think a lot of your styling is just working against you.

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

html {
  font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;
}

#logo {
  position: absolute;
  width: 25%;
  left: 0;
  height: auto;
  image-resolution: 100%;
}

header {
  width: 100%;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-evenly;
}

.navspace {
  justify-content: end;
  position: relative;
  right: -15%;
}

nav {
  position: relative; /* <- mispelled positio[n] */
}

ul {
  display: flex;
  list-style: none;
}

li {
  margin: 40px;
}

.product {
  position: absolute; /* I hate position absolute. Hate it deeply. Basically refuse to use it. It never works the way I want it to. More on this in response below */
  top: 15%;
}

#leads {
  width: 100vw;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  text-align: center;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

.title {
  padding: 2%;
}

#logo-green {
  width: 5vw;
  height: auto;
  margin-right: 5vw;
}

#Features {
  margin-left: 27%;
  display: flex;
  align-items: left;
  justify-content: left;
  text-align: left;
  padding: 5%;
}

#Price { /* be careful, classes and Ids are case sensitive*/
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: left;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 3%;
  margin-left: 27%;
}

.price {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  text-align: left;
}

.pricelist {
  width: 100%;
  max-height: 400px;
  text-align: center;
  position: absolute;
  display: inline-flex; /* technically, unless this object has a sibling, making it inline-flex while it is position: absolute; won't really change anything... though it could in unexpected ways. More below*/
  justify-content: center; 
}

.class {
  width: 300px;
  height: 300px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  margin: 20px;
}

.class>h1 {
  width: 100%;
  height: 10%;
  background-color: blanchedalmond;
  padding: 2%;
  font-size: large;
}

#medium,
#pika,
#base {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.class>h2 {
  margin: 5% 0 5% 0;
}

.class>ul {
  display: grid;
  display: flex;/* display grid is just being overridden by display flex here, so there's no point in keeping it */
  justify-content: center;
  flex-direction: column;
  gap: 2px;
}

.class>li {
  position: relative;
}
```

```html
<link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Montserrat' rel='stylesheet'>

<!-- tabella nav -->
<header>
  <div>
    <img id="logo" src="img/LIGHTSPEED.png" alt="" />
  </div>
  <!-- bhr -->
  <div class="navspace">
    <nav id="nav-link">
      <ul>
        <li>Features</li>
        <li>Price</li>
        <li>Contacts</li>
      </ul>
    </nav>
  </div>
</header>
<main class="product">
  <!-- form -->
  <section id="leads">
    <h2 class="title">Most efficient way to light your life</h2>
    <form action="">
      <input class="email" type="email" required placeholder="Enter your email" columns="10">
      <input class="submit" type="submit" value="Get Shocked">
    </form>
  </section>
  <!-- features -->
  <section>
    <div id="Features">
      <div id="green">
        <img id="logo-green" src="img/294432.png" alt="">
      </div>
      <div class="feature">
        <h2>Only from renovable energy</h2>
        <p>Coming from water and earth termal energy</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </section>
  <!-- price -->
  <section>
    <div id="Price">
      <div id="cheap">
        <img id="logo-green" src="img/low-price.png" alt="">
      </div>
      <div class="price">
        <h2>Prices you have never seen</h2>
        <p>With our funding system you might get some solar panels</p>
        <p>and who knows... we might pay you your energy.</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </section>
  <div class="pricelist">
    <div class="class" id="base">
      <h1>BASE LEVEL</h1>
      <h2>49€</h2>
      <ul>
        <li>Standart power transmission</li>
        <li>Change power output by your personal profile</li>
        <li>Client Support 10am-20am</li>
      </ul>
    </div>
    <div class="class" id="medium">
      <h1>MEDIUM LEVEL</h1>
      <h2>59€</h2>
    </div>
    <div class="class" id="pika">
      <h1>PIKACHU LEVEL</h1>
      <h2>149€</h2>
    </div>
  </div>
</main>
```

First off, while it is somewhat a personal choice and somewhat just the way most people use CSS these days: I hate position: absolute. It never acts the way you want it to, it's very difficult to get it to be responsive, and there are better ways to do it these days. The problem with absolute is that it simultaneously breaks an object out of the standard flow of the document, but it also gets rid of the object's ability to affect other objects in the document. This means that a div with position:absolute will no longer push down its sibling objects (things next to it), hold space within the parent object (the thing holding it will act like it has nothing inside it). While it's more complicated, using grid to break objects out of the normal document flow is more predictable.

Let's take a look at your code simply without position: absolute:

https://jsfiddle.net/slingtruchoice/sye5wbmu/

already, things aren't breaking outside of your boxes.

Your best bet to get things to align is to use use margin and display:block. Remember, inline items don't hold their own line in a document, they allow other inline items to butt up next to them in the same line, so they won't be affected by margin and padding in the same way. display:inline-block fixes some of that, but not everything.

i literally have this as a poster in my office. I've been doing this for ten years and still use it daily: https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/

if an item is overflowing out of the container, it's because the container isn't recognizing that it needs to be affected by the child's size. This either means that the parent has a fixed size that overrides the child's desire to make the parent bigger (like a pregnant lady wearing a corset, as my teacher always said... such a weird image).

It may also mean that the child's size isn't affecting things around it, such as a position:absolute or display:inline item that is acting weird. If you have display:flex and flex-wrap: nowrap on the parent, but the children are set to have a size larger than the parent object, then they will overflow.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I've seen a lot of content for learning CSS where it's used position:absolute. I've been using all the knowledge that I have and most of the time I just guess or try every line that comes in my mind about what line should I write and it works ahah I'll try to better understand the positioning in order to not use it since I really felt that 'it's difficult to get it responsive' it's like trying to make a lsd kid behave.

Comment: @mvrxw it is 100% super important to understand, especially when learning, but in reality it's something you'll probably avoid because of the way it breaks things easily. So don't feel like you have to justify the use, i totally understand. I learned flex and grid best by playing with flex and grid generators online like https://the-echoplex.net/flexyboxes/ and https://cssgrid-generator.netlify.app/

Comment: Hi! Just wanted to thank you for your advice. https://jsfiddle.net/mvrxw/2rd15b0a/ I reproduced it without using the position tag! It was much better and predictable! My last problem is to control the icons, can't understand how to center them in the mid page and align them to the right in the footer.

Comment: @mvrxw let's use flex for this. Like i said, i literally have this as a poster in my office: https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/ . Couple of things right off the bat: ul>li is "Unordered List > List Item" so in your footer you have one ```<li>``` wrapping all of your icons. If you were doing this as a true list, you would need each icon wrapped with its own li tag, then the UL around all the LIs. But, instead, all you need to do is wrap a div around each icon, then use flexbox. I'll add a comment with an updated fiddle in a few minutes.

Comment: @mvrxw i've added a ton of comments to the html and css that I hope are helpful! https://jsfiddle.net/slingtruchoice/3xtyz7c5/

Comment: Thx! Not only you corrected my mistakes, you literally changed my view to approach CSS and mindset!

Comment: @mvrxw happy to help! I've got a new account here, so if you felt it was appropriate I'd really appreciate it if you selected my answer as correct to this question. I'm glad I was able to figure some stuff out for you.

Answer (score 0):

I'm sure about what icons you are talking about, I would be happy to help you If can clarify  the issue. Now about the why your `li` items are overflowing over their container.

In your CSS on the line number 94 and 103 you set `max-height: 400px;` and `height: 300px;` because of that your `li` items are overflowing.

One way you can fix this bye removing fix height and set the value `height: auto;` that will make the parent container automatically grow based on their child element, or you can give your `ul` element a class or ID and then set `overflow-y: scroll;` to that ID or class.

Comment: Thx for your reply, this is what it looks like https://imgur.com/49EpwJZ the problem is the the middle part is very ugly to see. I want to obtain something like https://product-landing-page.freecodecamp.rocks/ middle part (premium, fast shipping etc) with their respective logos.

Answer (score 0):

This is the code [freecodecamp](https://product-landing-page.freecodecamp.rocks/) is using to design the middle section with the icon.

```css
.grid {
     display: flex;
}
 #features .icon {
     display: flex;
     align-items: center;
     justify-content: center;
     height: 125px;
     width: 20vw;
     color: darkorange;
}
 #features .desc {
     display: flex;
     flex-direction: column;
     justify-content: center;
     height: 125px;
     width: 80vw;
     padding: 5px;
}
```

```html
<!-- Wrapper -->
<div class="grid">
  <!-- Icon -->
  <div class="icon">
    <i class="fa fa-3x fa-fire"></i>
  </div>
  <!-- /Icon -->
  <!-- Description -->
  <div class="desc">
    <h2>Premium Materials</h2>
    <p> Our trombones use the shiniest brass which is sourced locally. This will increase the longevity of your purchase. </p>
  </div>
  <!-- /Description -->
</div>
<!-- /Wrapper -->
```

Now let me explain what is going on here. The `div` with the class name `grid` is the parent element for both `icon` and the `desc` So they set display of `grid` to `display: flex;` and give both child element fix width `width: 20vw;` and `width: 80vw;`

And I like to add one little note, That If you are using `position: absolute;` to any element then It's a good idea to set Its parent to `position: relative;` That would make working with position a lot easier.